# JavaMail SMTP fails with iCloud

Tags: jakarta-mail

with the following props I create a new session but it fails with

```
javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.mail.me.com, port: 587; nested exception is:
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Handshake failed

"mail.smtp.starttls.enable" -> "true"
"mail.smtp.port" -> 587
"mail.smtp.host" -> "smtp.mail.me.com"
"mail.smtp.auth" -> "true"
"mail.smtp.ssl.enable" -> "true"
```

If I remove the mail.smtp.ssl.enable property it works fine. Also I tested with many other email carriers but only icloud fails (it uses password based authentication).

Does anybody have a working example with iCloud using JavaMail?

Comment: You've enabled both SSL and STARTTLS; you don't need both.  If one of them work with iCloud, use that one.

Comment: As Bill pointed out it is a proper solution to remove mail.smtp.ssl.enable property as soon as mail.smtp.starttls.enable is added. Thank you Bill

Comment: Hi Bill, I've encountered another carrier where the only difference is the port 465 and have to have both SSL and STARTTLS. I wonder why? Is it a general rule that with port 587 I should have only STARTTLS and with port 465 I should have SSL and STARTTLS?